# Extract all rows when specific column matches more then once

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table in my DB

```
|id|name |company_id|role           |
|1 |test1|11        |READADMIN      |
|2 |test2|11        |WRITEADMIN     |
|3 |test3|11        |READWRITEADMIN |
|4 |test4|12        |READADMIN      |
|5 |test5|12        |WRITEADMIN     |
|6 |test6|12        |READWRITEADMIN |
|7 |test6|11        |READADMIN      |
|8 |test7|13        |READADMIN      |
|9 |test8|12        |READADMIN      |
|10|test9|12        |READADMIN      |
```

My goal is to extract all admins that have role `READADMIN` with same `company_id`, and count of this users should be more then 1.

In general I expect to get the following result:

```
|id|name |company_id|role     |
|1 |test1|11        |READADMIN|
|7 |test6|11        |READADMIN|
|4 |test4|12        |READADMIN|
|9 |test8|12        |READADMIN|
|10|test9|12        |READADMIN|
```

I've created select below, but I am not sure in their accuracy and performance:

```
SELECT id, name, company_id, role
FROM  admin
WHERE  company_id IN(SELECT CO.id 
FROM company CO 
       join admin AU 
       ON CO.id = AU.company_id 
WHERE  role = 'READADMIN'
GROUP  BY CO.id 
HAVING Count(AU.id) > 1) 
AND role = 'READADMIN';
```

Would be good to know optimal approach for the mentioned task.

Comment: Thanks, already updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM admin a
WHERE a.role = 'READADMIN'
AND EXISTS ( SELECT 'a'
             FROM admin a2
             WHERE a2.role = a.role
             AND a2.company_id = a.company_id
             AND a2.id <> a.id
            )
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess it is that I am looking about. Could you explain for what purposes we need to extract 'a' in subselect?

Comment: EXISTS function is true when the subselect have at least one row is not important the content but you must put something into the SELECT.. I choose 'a' but you can write SELECT * .... It's irrelevant for the query

Answer (score 1):

I guess that'll work :

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, name, company_id, role 
FROM admin WHERE role='READADMIN' GROUP BY CO.id
```

I'm not sure if that what you meant. What I understood from your question is that you want to get all the users that their role is 'READADMIN' and you don't want any duplicates in the results.

Comment: No, I 've updated question with actual and result tables. Additionally your select doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

why not :

```
SELECT id, name, company_id, role
FROM  admin
WHERE role = 'READADMIN'
GROUP  BY company_id 
HAVING Count(company_id) > 1 
   ;
```

Comment: you cannot group by with  `name, company_id, role` in `SELECT`

Comment: sorry about that it needs to be on company_id not id. I ran the script with your data and it seems to work. you can add an order by clause on id if you want to change the order

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should grant only one access to table, better check plan for yourself.

```
select id, 
       name, 
       company_id, 
       role
  from (
       select id, 
              name, 
              company_id, 
              role, 
              count(distinct id) over (partition by company_id) as cn
         from admin
        where role = 'READADMIN'
       )
 where cn > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Obviously you won't need the `with` if you have an actual table already:

```
with admin as
(select 1 id,'test1' name,11 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual
union
select 2 id,'test2' name,11 company_id, 'WRITEADMIN' role from dual
union
select 3 id,'test3' name,11 company_id, 'READWRITEADMIN' role from dual
union
select 4 id,'test4' name,12 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual
union
select 5 id,'test5' name,12 company_id, 'WRITEADMIN' role from dual
union
select 6 id,'test6' name,12 company_id, 'READWRITEADMIN' role from dual
union
select 7 id,'test6' name,11 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual
union
select 8 id,'test7' name,13 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual
union
select 9 id,'test8' name,12 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual
union
select 10 id,'test9' name,12 company_id, 'READADMIN' role from dual)

select admin.id, admin.name, admin.company_id, admin.role
from admin 
inner join 
(select company_id, role 
from admin
where role = 'READADMIN'
group by company_id, role having count(*) > 1) grouped
on admin.company_id = grouped.company_id
and admin.role = grouped.role;
```